# Add classes to li tags in a ul list as an index

Tags: jquery, addclass

$().addClass to `<li>` tags in a `<ul>`

example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="1"></li>
    <li class="2"></li>
    <li class="3"></li>
    <li class="4"></li>
    <li class="5"></li>
</ul>
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul > li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(i + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul > li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass((i + 1).toString());
});
```

or

```
$('ul > li').addClass(function(i) {
    return (i + 1).toString();
});
```

Comment: shouldnt it be ul's children? ul.each will be all the uls on the page.

Answer (score 2):

The nicest way is with the callback argument to [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$('li').addClass(function(i) {
    return i + 1;
});
```

The function provided is run once for each element in the selection.  The first argument is the 0-based index of the element in the selection (the second is the old class value, but that's unimportant here).  The return value is added to the element's current classes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if anyone else even tested their answers with the function callback, cause none of them at least work on my Chrome/FF4. You need to convert the integer to string.

```
$('ul > li').addClass(function(i) {
    return (i+1).toString();
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Cx3DX/